# objects.all() is not returning all items from DB

Tags: django

I am following an online course about Django and I am encountering a strange problem:
When I am referring to my db entry and when I am expecting to get all entries, I only receive the field that I designated to be returned as a string when I defined the class.

My files are as follow:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class About_me(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    linked_in = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import About_me

# Create your views here.

def cv(requests):
    cv = About_me.objects.all()
    return render(requests, 'cv/cv.html', {'cv': cv})
```

cv.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>About me</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>CV</h1>
        {% for item in cv %}
            <p>{{item}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I am expecting to get a list with all fields: name, position, about, etc... but I am getting only the Name and to be honest I don't understand why.

Since I am in a learning project, I would better like to know why is this happening rather than just fix it.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About me</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>CV</h1>
    {% for item in cv %}
        <p>item.name}</p>
        <p>item.position}</p>
        ....
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```